# What is the date format for value "43857.33" in R?

Tags: r, date, time

I have in data set values for "date_time" feature like 43857.33, 43857.43 and etc. and can't find any correct transformation into the correct date and time values.

Example:

```r
as_datetime(43857.33)
```

gives me "1970-01-01 12:10:57 UTC" that is wrong because I expect value around 2020 year.

Any ideas about actual value?

Answer (score 3):

If the date is from Excel, `as.Date(43857, origin = "1899-12-30")` gives `"2020-01-27"`

For time (decimal) values, you can use `library("datetimeutils")` and `convert_date(43857.33, type = "Excel", fraction = TRUE, tz = "")` gives me (in my timezone) `"2020-01-27 07:55:12 PST"`

Comment: Yes, it is Excel. Thanks!]

Comment: I have added the 'time' case to my answer